# wrapfigure in titleformat

Tags: titlesec, wrapfig

#### General overview

For each `\section` i try to put `BAZ` in wrapfigure in the right just in front of the section’s title but in the right side of the page.

#### MWE

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}%
[%
  \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{1cm}BAZ\end{wrapfigure}% Relevant section
]



\begin{document}

\section{foo}  Lipsum lorem 

\section{bar}

\end{document}
```

As you see, I put the Wrapfigure`s command inside the last optional parameter.

#### What documentation said

Moreover and according to *Titlesec’s mannual* (page 4):

> ```
> \titleformat{<_command_>}[<_shape_>]{<_format_>}{<_label_>}{<_sep_>}{<_before-code_>}[<_after-code_>]
> ```
>
> […]
>
> • <*after-code*> is code following the title body. The typeset material is in vertical mode with `hang`, `block` and `display`; in horizontal mode with `runin` and `leftmargin` (2.7 with the latter, at the beginning of the paragraph). Otherwise is ignored. Penalties in this argument may lead to unexpected results.

#### Running (here the problem appear)

Apparently, everything is ok, but when I compile using `xelatex`, I get the following output:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.13 \section{foo}
                    Lipsum lorem
?
```

#### Other tries

I also tried to put the Wrapfigure’s expression inside the `<before-code>` but I basically get the same output. It doesn’t seams to help

### The question

So how to put a wrapfigure with each section using `\titleformat` ?

Comment: I don't use `titlesec`, but I'd be surprised if this worked, given the restrictions on use of `wrapfigure`.

Comment: Unless you are wedded to `wrapfigure` + `\titleformat`, you might want to edit your question to say what your actual goal is.